# Botón para seleccionar el contenido de un GridView: aspx y C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Cómo podría configurar un botón que me seleccione TODOS los datos de las columnas de un GridView. Tengo configurado un botón con código java:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function CopyGridView()
{
 var div = document.getElementById('GRILLA');
div.contentEditable = 'true';
var controlRange;
if (document.body.createControlRange) {
controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
controlRange.addElement(div);
controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
}
div.contentEditable = 'false';
}
</script>
```

Pero me copia TODA la Grilla, junto con los titulos de cada columna. Es por ello que eh querido intentar solo copiar los datos, sin guardarlos en el portapapeles o mandarlo a un documento en Excel.

Comment: Que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Nada, es que la verdad no se qué ocupar para hacerlo.

Comment: Si no pones lo que intentaste o investigaste la pregunta va a ser cerrada. Siempre tenes que poner que hiciste hasta ahora.

Comment: Ya eh editado la pregunta.

Comment: no recuerdo que tipo de objeto es el gridview en la pagina? es una tabla ? tal vez esta respuesta que hace el select a un rango de una tabla de javascript sea lo que estas buscando https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044616/select-a-complete-table-with-javascript-to-be-copied-to-clipboard

Comment: Hola @Mike gracias por tu respuesta, pero quisiera saber si podrías orientarme un poco sobre como modifico el código a manera que no me copie los títulos de las columnas, si no solamente las filas que contienen la información